# Regular Expression to remove all lines containing only 1 word

Tags: regex, sed

I am attempting to create a regex that will find any line that contains exactly one word on it. Words separated by a hyphen or symbol (e.g test-word) or leading white space should still be treated as a single word.

```
$cat file1
this line has many words
hello
  test-hi
this does aswell
```

---

Using the regular expression

`'/^\s*(\w+)\s$/GM'`

Returns only "hello" and ignores "test-hi"

I am able to capture all single words but not ones with hyphens etc!

Comment: not sure what you mean by `G` and `M` flags for sed.. could you add some details why you are using them and if your sed version supports them?

Comment: Hi, I was building the expression in my browser using regexr.com. Without the Global flag I was not able to capture all the lines in my testing. I am still quite green to it all so may not be going in the right direction with it, if it seems odd. Cheers

Comment: oh ok, online sites like regexr may be useful, but you need to use them only for those particular languages(it will be mentioned somewhere on the page).. regex syntax and features vary a lot between programming languages and cli tools and even between different implementations of the same tool.. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y for details..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easier to do with `awk`, by default it will separate each record into fields based on one or more continuous whitespaces and whitespace at start/end of line won't be part of field calculations

```
$ awk 'NF==1' ip.txt
hello
  test-hi
$ awk 'NF>1' ip.txt
this line has many words
this does aswell
```

`NF` is a built-in variable that indicates number of fields in the input record

Comment: Although this doesn't use a regex, its simple and works perfectly. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^\s*([\w-]+)\s*$
```

which adds support for hyphens, makes the second `\s` match "zero or more" spaces. Keep your `GM` flags.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/67C8Q0/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\S` to match any non whitespace character:

```
'/^\s*(\S+)\s$/GM'
```